# Add source set subdirectory for custom language

Tags: gradle, project-structure, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write a plugin for gradle for python language. 
I would like to keep python sources the same way as for another languages, for example in `<project root>/src/main/python`.

In other words, I don't want to add directory like `main` in example above, but rather `python`.

I cannot find any explanation how can I do this. I know how to add custom source set, but not how to extend them.

I've tried analysing gradle java and groovy plugins, but they both have quite a different approach, and many of those classes aren't well documented (it's internal API, so that's not so bad).
I also tried googling "add source set subdir gradle", "custom source set subdirectory gradle", etc. All the results (for queries that I've asked, maybe I should have rephrased it in some way I didn't try) were about custom source sets (like integrationTest), not their subdirs for different languages or resources.

Yes, I know that python project structure doesn't work like JVM-based languages, but that's not the point of the question. Consider it language-agnostic and don't care that it's python.

**==EDIT==**

This apparently needs clarification.

I want to add subdirectories to each and every source set of the project. Normally I'd like to add `<project root>/src/main/python` and `<project root>/src/test/python`.
If user explicitly created new source set, for example `integTest`, I'd like to add `<project root>/src/integTest/python`.

I need it to be recognized as directory containing code, so that e.g. `idea` plugin will mark them as proper source-related directories.

Comment: You'd like to keep python sources under `<project root>/src/main/python` but without `main`?

Comment: A [python plugin](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/08/introducing--py-gradle--an-open-source-python-plugin-for-gradle) for Gradle was made public in 2016. The source and documentation are on [github](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle).

Comment: Wow. @user1241663 - thanks a lot, I'm sooooo glad to see that.